# What's the meaning of 'lips of' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I encountered the following sentence while reading a book:

> We soon discovered that many slips are possible between the cup of a
> promising idea and the lips of real-life applications, and that only a
> thorough understanding of these intermediate steps can turn a
> promising idea into something really useful and practical.

I can figure out the meaning from the context:

There might be many dangers between ideas and applications of the ideas. So the idea alone is not enough.

But I cannot figure out what the 'lips of' means there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quoted phrase is just a modern allusion to the aphorism, “There's many a slip 'twixt the cup and the lip“. The literal meaning is: though You might mean or plan to take a drink from a cup, completing the task without spillage is never certain until after the task is complete. This is synonymous to the idiom, “Don’t count your chickens before they hatch”

Comment: It might be better described as an allusion to the aphorism.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan - Sure, why not.

Comment: `'twixt` is short for `betwixt`, an archaic form of `between`.

Comment: Why is it many a slip instead of many slips?

Comment: @kevin012 It's another example of archaic usage.

Comment: @kevin012 - It is meant to be poetic. An aphorism, like many things, is best remembered when it has rhythm, rhyme, reason, alliteration, visual imagery, an emotional impact, perceived usefulness or future requirement, etc.